# Prolog rewriting equations

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create a rewrite predicate in SWI-Prolog that checks if an equation can be simplified then replaces the old one with the new one. I have tried to do the following:

Lets say I have the following equation `x+0` and I want to replace/rewrite it with `x`.

I have tried the following:

```
simplify(X,X) :- primitive(X).
simplify(X,Y) :- evaluable(X), Y is X.
simplify_exp(X,Y) :- rewrite(X,X1), simplify(X1,Y).
simplify_exp(X,X).
primitive(X) :- atom(X).
rewrite(X+0,X).
rewrite(0+X,X).
rewrite(x+1+(y-1),x+y).
rewrite(X*X,X^2).
rewrite(X^0,1).
rewrite(0*X,0).
rewrite(X*N,N*X) :- number(N).
```

`simplify(X)` will return `x` to me, then I need to rewrite which is fine.

However when I have a longer equation lets say `(power(a)+b)-(x+0)`, it won't find `simplify(X)` hence I cannot rewrite it.

Can I get any recommendation/help please?

Comment: Your example expression `(power(a)+b)-(x+0)` is of the form `X - Y` but you don't have any rewrite rules that handle that case.

Comment: [It is morning for me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Tthank you that has been sorted now. However what happens in the following case it is given that x=0. I want to simply it in x+1=1. but when I try the rewrite it tries to rewrite the full expression x+1=1 which is false,@lurker.

Answer (score 0):

The `rewrite` predicate can be re-written more concisely:

```
:- initialization(main).
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars). 

main :- rewrite(x*0,Output),writeln(Output).

rewrite(X+0,X1) :- rewrite(X,X1).
rewrite(0+X,X+0).
rewrite(X,X) :- atom(X);number(X).
rewrite(X+1+(Y-1),X1+Y1) :- rewrite(X,X1),rewrite(Y,Y1).
rewrite(X*X,X1^2) :- rewrite(X,X1).
rewrite(X^0,1).
rewrite(0*X,0).
rewrite(X*0,Output) :- rewrite(0*X,Output).
rewrite(X*N,N*X1) :- number(N),(\+number(X)),rewrite(X,X1).
rewrite(N*X,N*X1) :- rewrite(X*N,N*X1).
```

To simplify more complicated arithmetic expressions, you can use the [Reduce-Algebraic-Expressions](https://github.com/SJasoria/Reduce-Algebraic-Expressions) library.